# How did someone with 1 rep post a comment?

Tags: support, comments

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26066997/javascript-onclick-not-working-in-ie), [this user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4047954/harutyun-abgaryan) posted a comment. I thought you had to have at least 50 rep to do that. The only time I've seen this allowed is if the person commenting was also the person who posted the question, which doesn't appear to be the case here.

Comment: Most likely the user posted an answer, and (a mod) converted it into a comment from a VLQ or NAA flag. The content of the comment (how the link is formatted) suggests that was at one point an answer.

Comment: @gunr2171 - yeah I suppose that's possible (and likely), especially since there's no way for non-mods to tell if that was done which would make it look the way it does. There should be a mod icon next to comments like that the way the pencil icon shows up when you edit a comment.

Comment: @j08691 Another option: Was the user put to the [penalty box](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/) meanwhile?

Comment: Wait, if the comment _was_ an answer, it should still be viewable for 10k users, or does "moving it to a comment" permanently destroy the answer?

Comment: @gunr2171 If it was posted as an answer and converted to a comment it would show up as a deleted answer.  That there are no deleted answers tells us that either a dev went in and hard deleted it, or there was never a time where it was visible as a real answer.  That situation *would* be the case given what happens in the situation described in my answer, leaving it as the only option possible here (other than a dev intervening).

Comment: Doh, I should've asked this here instead of posting my comment in the original question :)

Comment: And on the uber meta http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/233960

Comment: @Servy, gunr2171: The answer submission is prevented altogether. The only thing that's inserted is a comment.

Comment: Test answer, hope this works http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/272355/73226 (and I can edit it)

Comment: Can anyone else see "**Trivial answer converted to comment**" on my comment (answer) above? Or is it only visible to me?

Comment: @damryfbfnetsi Yes, it worked, and is visible to everyone else.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET I don't see it anymore, though...

Comment: @BradleyDotNET No, what I mean is I can't see the "**Trivial answer converted to comment**" designator anymore...

Comment: @damryfbfnetsi Ah, yes, that is gone.

Comment: I deleted my comment asking if there was a maximum rep limit for automatic trivial answer conversion because I saw I'd missed it was only for internal links, but my new trivial answer was still created and has remained for an hour...

Answer (score 50):

When you try to post a very short answer containing a link it'll be automatically converted to a comment when you try to post it.  The comment is posted even if you don't have enough rep to comment.

Comment: With all the hurdles in the system to ensure quality content, this seems like a stupid thing to have.

Comment: _automatically?_ When did that happen?

Comment: @j08691 Agreed.

Comment: @gunr2171 I don't know how long its been around, a fair while.  I don't see it actually happen often though.  Not sure what the exact criteria are for meeting it.

Comment: Specifically it has to be an internal link IIRC. So it is not a possible avenue for spam links.

Comment: How many more times am I gonna have to bounty my question before someone will do something about this?

Comment: @MartinSmith: the comment can be edited for 5 minutes, so someone could (technically) post a legit but short comment, then change it to spam.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy I tested that before with a dummy account with <50 rep and didn't see an edit link.

Comment: @MartinSmith: hmm, maybe it changed, I tried it a long while back and  remembered being able to edit the contents after posting at the time.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy - My test was pretty much when the trivial answer functionality came out. I haven't tested recently. If you were testing with a <50 rep account maybe the change was in the other direction.

Comment: @BoltClock 6 to 8 more, not times, just 6 to 8

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy I retested and you're right. It does show the edit link even for a new user with 1 rep. [per the comment I left here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7869172/when-will-a-fast-forward-cursor-have-a-work-table-and-is-this-something-to-avoi?noredirect=1#comment40914989_7869172)

Answer (score 9):

This answer tries to cover all cases in which users with less than 50 reputation commented on posts. [Servy's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/272267) explains the case the OP asks about.

---

There are 4 possible scenarios for how this can happen:

1. [Automatic answer-to-comment conversion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/98955)

   > Trivial answers containing a link to another question in the network are automatically converted to comments on the question [...]

   In this case, there would be no visible trace of the user's attempt to post an answer. Only the comment would be visible.
2. [Moderator converted an answer to a comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/278933)

   Answers can be manually converted to a comment by moderators. When a moderator converts an answer to a comment, the answer remains in a deleted state, where it will be visible to users with privileges to see deleted posts, with an annotation that the answer was converted to a comment by the moderator who performed the action.
3. [Post authors can comment even without enough reputation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19757)

   The author of a question can comment on their own question and answers to their question, and the author of an answer can comment on their own answer, even without having [the privileges to do so (which is 50 reputation on Stack Overflow)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).
4. A user who had [the commenting privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) when they posted the comment but then lost that privilege (perhaps temporarily; e.g., through suspension or by a decrease in reputation).

Comment: Hmm, as usual, [that linked MSE answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19757) is not quite correct. Not surprising, as this portion was added by someone who doesn't even have moderator privileges. There is no limit on the length of answers which can be converted to comments. However, the resulting comment will be clipped to the maximum comment length, which is 600 characters. It is possible for a mod to work around this by undeleting and re-converting the answer to a comment, with some editing of the comments. The claim that the Markdown is unchanged is also wrong; links are rewritten.