# I wrote an answer, had only 45 reputation points and it got posted as comment to question

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, automatic-comments

[Whoa!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38263094/usage-of-a-picture-instead-of-rectangle-shape-in-c-sharp)

I just have 45 reputation points so I am not allowed to comment on the question and can only give an answer. I went ahead to do that and to my surprise, it got posted as a comment to the question and not as an answer.

Comment: Yeah. That needs to stop happening. It's ridiculous.

Comment: ^ posting link-only answers, that is ...

Comment: @Glorfindel: Well, both. This feature encourages people to try and post link-only answers. We can't make people stop posting link-only answers, but this feature is stupid and just needs to *go away*.

Comment: You mean http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38263094/usage-of-a-picture-instead-of-rectangle-shape-in-c-sharp#comment63946264_38263094, presumably. **It was not an answer**. If you can't comment, *don't comment*; you only need a little more rep to get the privilege.

Comment: @jonrsharpe What do you want to say by mentioning the link separately? And try to see the problem! I posted it as an answer but somehow dramatically it got converted to a comment.

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to ask with *"What do you want to say by mentioning the link separately?"* There are two problems: 1. the auto-conversion to comment; and 2. **you posting a link-only answer**. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/248731

Comment: @BoltClock I guess the blame's not on me then. Such anomaly! If there's the middle space where the question cannot be marked duplicate and also that posting relatable question links which presents a bit diversification because of variety of answers there and difference of question to open up minds, I guess it should be allowed as it'd be of help.

Don't care much for the orientation then; comment or answer. But this shows a buggy way to comment if you have an answer posted on some site and not enough reputation points.

Comment: Err, there seems to be a bit of miscommunication here. The link jonrsharpe posted is conveniently directly to the comment that this meta is about, while the "whoa" link is only to the question and so people have to scout for the comment themselves.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer

Comment: Whoa this is annoying.

Comment: *the question cannot be marked duplicate* What do you mean? You gained the privilege to flag posts at 15 rep. What happened when you tried to flag it as a duplicate?

Comment: @BSMP It was a reply to BoltClock wherein I did not mean that I CANNOT flag a question as something; I just meant to say that some questions to which links can be provided as answers because they are simliar, are not identical enough to be marked duplicate. This was the middle space that I talked about where I landed and tried to justify that even if link-only answers are posted, they should be allowed, doesn't matter if it gets converted to a comment. But the "comment" should not be totally removed.

Comment: He is getting downvotes because he tried to give answer with only link? or he asked wrong question but seems he thought its issue that's why he is on meta so why _DOWNVOTES_??

Comment: @Leothelion - Probably due to disagreement with the OP breaking the rules in the first place.

Answer (score 6):

As demonstrated by my comment above (or the picture of it below) Stack Exchange will automatically convert so-called Trivial answers to comments. These are answers which consist of a single link, or similar. [This behavior](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/98955/323179) is intended to encourage the understanding that a link on its own is not an answer.

It's perfectly OK to include a link in your answer, but you should do so as an additional optional resource, not part of the answer itself: like I'm about to.

Wait for it...

If you'd like to read more about why links aren't answers, take a look here:
[Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer)

[image: Trivial Answer-come-Comment]

Comment: For curiosity's sake, when was this implemented? I haven't seen mention of it before

Comment: @CubeJockey It only says "Trivial answer converted to comment" to the answer's OP. Chances are, you ran into this and didn't realize it. It has been around [since 2014](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272265/how-did-someone-with-1-rep-post-a-comment/272267#comment98669_272267) at least.

Comment: @Laurel, sure, that would make sense. Any insight on how long this has been present?

Comment: @CubeJockey The earliest mention of this feature is from [July 2011](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/98955/323179)

Comment: @Laurel Thanks for digging that up. Looks like that Meta SE post is valuable input to this Q&A.

Comment: @CubeJockey What's strange is it's not in the FAQ...

Comment: @Laurel - They probably don't want low rep users deliberately posting answers that they know will get converted into comments.

Comment: @BSMP You mean link-only answers,right? Because it isn't ANY answer posted by low rep users. Been there, done that.

Comment: @AakashVerma - The link Laurel provided says that it happens with links to other questions on Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: @BSMP Not exactly a reply to what I said, but okay a neat back-foot deflect.